# Changing compiler

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-construction

Can I use compiler from VS 2010 while using VS2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your code. If you're developing in ANSI C++ you should be fine. If you're using MFC-specific functionality that was added for VS 2010, you may be out of luck.